# How to capture Android framebuffer in nexus5?

Tags: android, screenshot, framebuffer

I have to framebuffer capture test in nexus5 (Android version 4.4.4) but nexus5 Android framebuffer(/dev/graphics/fb0) access method does not work in the past.(nexus4, nexus s, one..)

Captured is a null data (black screen)

So, I want to find a way to capture framebuffer in nexus5.

Using the system to capture rootview currently in used, but can not write data to the framebuffer

It does not matter rooted, jni(application)

How to access Android screen framebuffer?
[my final goal is get framebuffer then imageprocess(gray / color model change etc..) my image rewrite framebuffer]

Thanks.